# Postgres search in jsonb array to exclude rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm make a search function for a user to rent a car and want to filter database rows.

I have a db field called unavailability that has some dates.

```
unavailability_field:
{2019-02-20,2019-02-21,2019-02-22,2019-02-23}
```

When a user search for availability in range 2019-02-18 / 2019-02-21 I want to loop through these days that user chooses and search if a given date is included in my unavailability field. So, if it's included i want to remove the row from results because that day the car is not available.

How can i do that in postgres?

Comment: The field you mentioned is not a valid json/jsonb. Please add the actual json.